# NullPointerException on setShareIntent using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to use ActionBarSherlock + ShareActionProvider in a SherlockActivity.
I've already checked this ( [NullPointerException using ShareActionProvider + actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633140/nullpointerexception-using-shareactionprovider-actionbarsherlock)) but it doesn't solve my problem.
I think the code is correct, but I keep getting FC and this logcat:

```
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.corsalini.david.calcolopesi.ActCalcolo.onCreateOptionsMenu(ActCalcolo.java:162)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockActivity.java:173)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:556)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.preparePanel(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:483)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.dispatchInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:273)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$1.run(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:988)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-25 15:31:26.758: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.miShare);
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
    // Set the default share intent
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_text));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_subject));
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);  //Line 162
    return true;
}
```

And here is the xml for the menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miPref"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        android:visible="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miReset"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_reset"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/reset"
        android:visible="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miShare"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/share" />
</menu>
```

EDIT 1:

I'm trying to add this line:
                 mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);

And now the NullPointerException is here. Is it possible that there is no such file and so i get the exception?

EDIT 2: Do not take care of EDIT 1
I've found that the problem was in the XML.
You have to use:

```
    android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

but i was still using the original android widget.
I have also included:

```
    menuItem.setActionProvider(mShareActionProvider);
```

in the activity, but i think it's redundant.

Now i've got two problems:
1. the app doesn't crash only if the "share" button doesn't show up in the action bar, if i try to put it on top of the list, the app crash and give the same logcat as the one posted here.
2. When i click "share" nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, let's walk through the information provided: "at com.corsalini.david.calcolopesi.ActCalcolo.onCreateOptionsMenu(ActCalcolo.java:162)"     What is on line 162 in ActCalcolo.java?

Comment: mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);  //Line 162
I'm sorry =)

Comment: I have never used ActionBarSherlock, but `mShareActionProvider` is null so this `menuItem.getActionProvider();` doesn't find anything (it simply returns null). Next we'll check the documentation...

Comment: I don't think i understood you answer. menuItem.getActionProvider() take the menuitem from the line above and the item is there for sure. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, the NPE is in line 162. The only variable that could cause this is `mShareActionProvider`, so when you initialized `mShareActionProvider` something went awry. `menuItem` is fine (no NPE here) so something about getActionProvider() and setting your ActionProvider in `miShare` is off. (But I not finding much documentation online... Still looking)

Comment: Just to be certain is `main_menu.xml` the Menu XML you posted?

Comment: Don't know why my last comment didn't show up, but yes, menu_main is the xml in the question.

Answer (score 6):

**Notes**

I have tried to duplicate your error and the only two ways I can cause `mShareActionProvider` to be `null` is to:

1. leave this out entirely: `android:actionProviderClass=...`
2. use the Android class: `android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"`

As you discovered in EDIT 2 the appropriate ActionBarSherlock code is:

```
android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
```

---

**Suggestions**

> 1) ... If I try to put (the menu item) on top of the list, the app crashes and gives the same logcat

Try creating a new menu XML file, save this as res/menu/temp_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/miShare"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Share" />
</menu>
```

And load it with:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.temp_menu, menu);
```

> 2) If "share" is in the overflow menu nothing happens when I select it.

This is an ActionBarSherlock backwards compatibility quirk detailed here, [Issue #455](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/455).

---

**Null Pointer Exception**

From a few of your comments, I want to clarify what exactly a NullPointerException is. When you tried adding this line:

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
```

You said:

> And now the NullPointerException is here. Is it possible that there is no such file and so I get the exception?

The reason the NPE moved here is because `mSharedActionProvider` is still null. You cannot reference the concept of `null.method()` or in your case `null.setShareHistoryFileName()`, this is what a NPE is. In other words, you cannot ask nothing to do something. It doesn't matter here whether the file exists or not, the app crashes *before* this point.

You can prove this for yourself in the debugger or by adding a line like this:

```
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
Log.w("NullPointerException", "Is mShareActionProvider null: " + (mShareActionProvider == null));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I cannot find this method, SupporteED is a bit strange and neither this or Support works. Plus, [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/527) the creator of ABS doesn't speak about getSupportedActionProvider() when he answer the question.

Comment: I don't think getSupportActionProvider exists, I get an error when i write it down, Eclipse doesn't find it with the autocompletition and i can't find it on the internet.
But the explanation on the nullpointerexception actually clarified the problem.

Comment: ' /**
     * Gets the {@link ActionProvider}.
     *
     * return The action provider.
     *
     * see ActionProvider
     * see #setActionProvider(ActionProvider)
     */
    public ActionProvider getActionProvider();'
This is the method in com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem.

Comment: I laughed at myself yesterday when I realized that I was reading what I _wanted_ to read, _not_ what was written. You're right: there is no such method as getSupportActionProvider(), my apologies. I installed ActionBarSherlock to try to solve this, I update my answer.

Comment: Following your suggestion i created a menu with only the shareprovider item, the activity doesn't crash, but if i click on the button nothing happens. I also get a very long list of method that didn't resolve from ABS. Here is a snippet from the log:
I/dalvikvm(564): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setTranslationX
-W/dalvikvm(564): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3511: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
I'll give up soon on this button =(

Comment: Do you have the latest 4.1.0 version?

Comment: Yes, downloaded just a few days ago!

Comment: @DavidCorsalini hi mate, have u solved this issue? I met the same issue and can't find out the reason. thx