# Null Pointer Exception - android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I am writing a simple program for last 2 hours, but did not get any solution of this small issue, using below code:

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Set up ShareActionProvider's default share intent
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share);

        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
                MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I am using Android App !!!");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

**main.xml:-**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
     <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

I am not getting where i am doing mistake in this small program... please let me know my mistake and help me to resolve this !

**Line number : 79**

```
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
```

I followed this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

**Log says:**

```
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 2012
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.learn2crack.tab.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:79)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-20 05:51:48.814: E/AndroidRuntime(2012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 05:51:51.484: I/Process(2012): Sending signal. PID: 2012 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you check if your `shareItem` is null?

Comment: and have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131873/null-pointer-exception-in-using-upport-library-share-action-provider and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358510/why-menuitemcompat-getactionprovider-returns-null

Comment: try `mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();`

Comment: what happens if you try the above?

Comment: @Raghunandan Cannot cast from ActionProvider to ShareActionProvider

Comment: you should be using shareactionprovider from the appcompact. make sure you have the right import

Comment: which import you are talking about ???

Comment: the import for ActionProvider

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was in proGuard. After I added this to the rules file the problem solved:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's work for me

```
ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(getActivity());
MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(shareItem, mShareActionProvider);
```