# ShareActionProvider is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, shareactionprovider

I have been searching for 3 or 4 days about a solution on this. I have tried: 
[Null Pointer exception in using support library share action provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131873/null-pointer-exception-in-using-support-library-share-action-provider)
or
[why MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358510/why-menuitemcompat-getactionprovider-returns-null) and some others
but still I get null on ShareActionProvider. I am pretty new on developing android apps so I really need some help.

My xml menu file is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/></menu>
```

and my fragment is:

```
public static class DailyActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Dailyshare";
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    public DailyActivityFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
        }else{
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "is null");
        }
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "this text will be shared");
        return shareIntent;
    }
}
```

as an import I have:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just create a ShareActionProvider and assign it.

```
mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider();
mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent())
MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, mShareActionProvider);
```

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well, just take care that you don't specify the action provider class in the menu XML file! Since the latest support library update that's not supported anymore together with this workaround!

Answer (score 12):

You have wrong namespace usage in XML:

> <menu xmlns:*android*="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>                 xmlns:*app*="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
>
> <item **android**:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"

should be ***app***:actionProviderClass (the provider class is from apk resources, not native android classes).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32602896/907576

Comment: hope this will help other people as well!