# ShareActionProvider not doing anything

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, shareactionprovider

I have been following the Android Development course on Udacity, and got to a lesson where we were to implement a `ShareActionProvider`. After attempting it myself, and then following what they did--I'm certain it's not working properly.

I'm putting the code in a Fragment; the correct item is present in the overflow menu, but when I click "Share", nothing happens. I noticed when I open the DetailsActivity, that the following appears in the logs:

`17493-17493/com.dummy.sunshine.app W/MenuItemCompat﹕ setActionProvider: item does not implement SupportMenuItem; ignoring`

I'm not sure what that means, but I couldn't find anything about it online. I would assume that clicking it is supposed to do something--however, they never go over what's supposed to happen after that lesson--so I'm a tad confused.

**DetailActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**DetailFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private static String mForecastStr;
    private final String TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public DetailFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent(); //allows us to get data from the screen that sent us to this activity
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT); //we get the EXTRA_TEXT that the ForecastFragment sent us
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                    .setText(mForecastStr);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    private Intent shareDetailForecast() {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastStr + "#SunshineApp");
        return sendIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail_fragment, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(getActivity());
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareDetailForecast());
        MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(menuItem, mShareActionProvider);

        if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareDetailForecast());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "mShareActionProvider is null...");
        }
    }
}
```

**menu_detail_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="5"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

**menu_detail.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.nxt3.sunshine.app.DetailActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

This is what the app looks like on the DetailActivity page:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that on your DetailActivity you are extending a FragmentActivity while you should be extending an [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) (which is a subclass of the FragmentActivity), as you are using an action bar on your activity and using the support library.

so you should replace this:

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

by this:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

and import the support library:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

I don't know if you already have it set, but you also need to set your AppTheme to be Theme.AppCompat or something similar on your AndroidManifest.xml. Something like below:

```
</manifest>     
   <application
       ...
       android:theme=""Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
       ... 
   </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm doing the same exercise in the Udacity and that worked for me, I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm following the course, but I'm targeting Lollipop and building with Lollipop. I shouldn't have to use `AppCompat`, should I? I thought I should only have to use that if I'm supporting lower versions of Android.

Comment: I've assumed you were targeting lower API as you are using the support libraries android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat and android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider, I believe you don't need to use those libraries if your target is the Lollipop. I haven't used the FragmentActivity, as I´m targeting lower version, but I believe as you are using an Action Bar you need to extend the activity to either the ActionBarActivity or the AppCompatActivity as stated on the note on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Comment: I had the same problem. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093706/shareactionprovider-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the share view appears beside the toolbar menu!

If yes, here is the right solution for your issue :

**DetailActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**DetailFragment.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";
        private String mForecastStr;

        public DetailFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            // The detail Activity called via intent.  Inspect the intent for forecast data.
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                        .setText(mForecastStr);
            }

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_detail_fragment, menu);

            // Retrieve the share menu item
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

            // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
            ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider =
                    (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

            // Attach an intent to this ShareActionProvider.  You can update this at any time,
            // like when the user selects a new piece of data they might like to share.
            if (mShareActionProvider != null ) {
                mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share Action Provider is null?");
            }
        }

        private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
            return shareIntent;
        }
}
```

**menu_detail_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

**menu_detail.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```